# generate a custom token on django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, token

I am developing an application which I wrote an api for it this api create a user by verifying it's phone number so then I want to generate him token the post request should be like this

```
{
"phone_number": "",
"username": "",
"bio',
"profilePic": null
}
```

and if model serializer is valid the output should be like this and it should generate a token for another requests

```
{
"phone_number": "",
"username": "",
"bio',
"profilePic": null,
"token": "28duw8he282hd2sszajqj"
}
```

so I want to create a customize auth class is there any one to help with my problem

this is the user model class

```
class WhIronUsers(models.Model):
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="phone_number", unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="username")
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="bio")
    profilePic = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/profile")
```

and this is the view which in this view I want to generate the token

```
from rest_framework import generics
from .serializers import WhIronUserSerializer
from .models import WhIronUsers


class WhIronUserView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = WhIronUserSerializer
    queryset = WhIronUsers.objects.all()


class WhIronDetailUserView(generics.RetrieveDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = WhIronUserSerializer
    queryset = WhIronUsers.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best practice but I will give it a go.

You can edit the user model like this:

```py
class WhIronUsers(models.Model):
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="phone_number", unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="username")
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="bio")
    profilePic = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/profile")
    verification_code = models.CharField(max_length=6)  # Assuming 6-digit OTP
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And make 2 parts of user registration.

The first part is where user enters his `username, bio, profilePic, phone_number`.

When new user completes this part, backend generates a `verification_code` and adds it to database.

The second part is to send the `verification_code` somehow to his phone number and at the verification view, you change `is_verified=True` if the input matches the `verification_code`.

After that, I suggest to use `JWT` auth token.